# Reading sefer in seforim store

Tags: jewish-books, gezel-stealing

Can one go to a sefroim store with the intention of not buying a Sefer and look into a sefer and read some of its contents? Is it considered stealing?

Comment: Sources would be great

Comment: You mean he had specific intention not to buy a book, or he just didn't have intention _to_ buy a book?

Answer (score 3):

See [this article](http://matzav.com/business-halacha-browsing-a-store-to-buy-online/) which cites mainly Choshen Mishpat for support.

In short - browsing is permitted as the store owner expects customers to browse. If, at the end, you don't buy because you didn't find what you wanted or didn't like the price, etc. that's fine. A nicer thing to do is to indicate this to the owner, but, it's not required.

However, if you have no intention to buy anything at all, this is a violation of oppressing your neighbor ("ona'ah), since the owner expects you to buy something, and you may be distracting him form attending to other serious customers.

An exception is if you walk into a very large or crowded Seforim store where the owner is unaware of individual customers entering or leaving. In that case, as long as you don't disturb the owner or his workers, you are fine, as the owner has no expectations.

Another possibility would be if the owner asks, "Can I help you" and you answer "I'm just browsing, I may not actually buy anything" and the owner is fine with this. In that case, the owner has given you permission not to buy and he clearly indicates that you have no obligation to do so.

You can also assist your friend who is buying, even if you're not. However, this only allows you to read books that your friend intends to buy.

Comment: "I may not actually buy anything" is different from "I definitely will not be buying anything."

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I saw your comment before I posted my answer. I think my answer addresses both. You can't enter the store with the intention of not buying anything. If you're not sure, you can. In a big Sefarim store where there are so many people or a multi-floor store where the owner is unaware of who enters, then even if you don't intend to buy, this is OK, providing you have no contact with the owner or workers.

Comment: If the situation is actually "I may not actually buy anything," I don't see why you'd have to go out of your way to tell the owner that. I think that is always assumed to be the case. If I go into a store and the thing I'm looking for isn't there or the price is too high, I might just leave. What do I accomplish by telling the owner that I might not buy anything? Nobody ever has an "obligation" to buy something when they walk into a store.

Comment: Considering "ayin tachat ayin" wouldn't it be fine to cause him ona'ah if his prices caused you ona'ah? ;)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt cute! However, you CAN negotiate the price and THEN walk out as there is no violation called "peh tachat peh" :-)

Comment: @DanF, I did not know that.

Comment: _"You can't enter the store with the intention of not buying anything."_ So to clarify, I can't follow my friend who is planning on buying something into a store?

Comment: @mevaqesh You can follow your friend who is the buyer (assuming he intends to buy something, that is.) But, if you read a sefer and you have no intention to buy, I think you run into the same problem. The fact that you are with your friend doesn't change the rules to let you read a sefer. You could, of course, read a sefer that HE intends to buy, esp. if it's for the purpose of advising him.

Comment: @DanF I think you're just making up rules according to what makes sense to you.

Comment: @Daniel If you come in with your friend, but you have no intention to buy, how does that change the rules that apply to reading any books that you want? It's no different than if you walked in alone. If the owner sees your friend reading a book, he expects him to buy, which was his intent. If he sees you read a book, he expects you (or your friend) to buy a book, too. But you have no intention to do so.

Comment: @DanF Do you have any evidence that actually reading the book is the thing that makes the owner expect you to buy something rather than just walking into the store? Maybe you and your friend are trying to find a book to buy together. I'm not saying you're definitely wrong. I'm just saying that you have brought no evidence to back your assertions.

Comment: @Daniel AH, I think I see your premise. What you're suggesting may be a separate M.Y. question. I'm suggesting further, that if the owner sees you handling merchandise or asking him or a worker for help, he assumes that you will buy (fair enough, right?) As for playing "mind games" - i.e. your friend reads a book he wants to buy, and you read a different book - how does the owner know what's what? Well, of course, that doesn't necessarily oppress the owner, but, it still may not be the right thing to do. And, I mentioned, already, that there shouldn't be any problems assisting your friend.

Comment: @DanF This question is about **halacha**. Whether something "is the right thing to do" is irrelevant. If you are going to make halachic claims, you should bring halachic evidence. Otherwise it's just your opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25924/discussion-between-danf-and-daniel).